# Как сделать input type="text" в firefox адекватным?

Tags: html, firefox

При записи чего-либо в `input` в firefox и потом удалении этого содержимого `backspace`'ом и если нажать `backspace` 1 раз больше чем кол-во символов в `input`'е, то курсор прыгает в конец, в других браузерах такого бага нет. Знаю, что мелочь, но меня раздражает... Может кто знает как бороться с таким багом?

Answer (score 2):

Это скорее всего у тебя такая бага. Протестировал в Firefox 14.0.1 - всё отлично работает. Правда у инпута, который тестирован нет атрибута type, но не думаю, что в нем дело

Comment: сейчас у кого-то еще попрошу протестировать. возможно и у меня баг...
да у друга стоит FF 14 у него тоже нет такого бага. Значит это что-то у меня или с FF 15.1 не так.

Comment: У меня 15.0.1, такой баг присутствует.